# Instantiate Nib Bad Access Code = 2

Tags: swift

```
func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView {
   let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
   let nib = UINib(nibName: "JobsView", bundle: bundle)
   let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView
   return view
}
```

Im trying to load my JobsView.xib file. However it is giving me bad access without any more information. How can I solve this error?

I've linked the class over from the File's Owner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load a UIView from nib in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857986/load-a-uiview-from-nib-in-swift)

Comment: Have you tried to load it with NSBundle.mainBundle() instead of forClass?

Comment: @NickCatib Tried and it doesn't work

Comment: @Exceptions have you solved the problem?

Comment: Did you get the solution?