# How to catch the click on the button in added XIB view (annotation)

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

1) I have the ViewController with the MapKit

1.1) I have added some pin's to Map

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate
```

2) I write the new classes for custom pin Callout and Annotation

```
class CustomPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {

class CustomCalloutView: UIView {
```

3) I haved created .xib for my custom pin callout
[image]

4) I created the button in my .xib, this button must do something, for example

```
    @IBAction func clickTest(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("aaaaa")
}
```

5) This button doesn't work

What is usually practice for this? I want to make my button working.
Button is blue:
[image]

All project you can see on Github: https://github.com/genFollowMe1/forStack
Thank you, sorry for English )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**for Objective C:**
https://github.com/nfarina/calloutview

**Update**

for swift

subclass the MKAnnotationView for custom call out and override the hitTest: and pointInside: methods.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class CustomCalloutView: MKAnnotationView {

@IBOutlet weak var name: UILabel!

@IBAction func goButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    print("button clicked sucessfully")
}

override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    let hitView = super.hitTest(point, withEvent: event)
    if hitView != nil {
        superview?.bringSubviewToFront(self)
    }
    return hitView
}

override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    let rect = self.bounds
    var isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point)
    if !isInside {
        for view in subviews {
            isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, point)
            if isInside {
                break
            }
        }
    }
    return isInside
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry, your solution is in Objective-C, i use Swift. I have custom callout and i can send variables to my .xib, but cant make working button..         `// init XIB`
       `let customView = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ViewCallout", owner: self, options: nil))[0] as! CustomCalloutView;`
  
      `let calloutViewFrame = customView.frame;`
   
     `let cpa = view.annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation`
      `cpa.name = "Company Name"`
       `customView.name.text = cpa.name`
     `view.addSubview(customView)`

Comment: you have to subclass MKAnnotationView for the customcalloutview(now your subclassing from UIView), add the view, buttons, lables in that subclass and override the hitTest: and pointInside: methods to achieve the button click.

Comment: You're right, i feeling it is right way. Do not tell me where to see manual for this overrided methods?? (hitTest and pointInside)

Answer (score 0):

The way you have to do it's to make a reference of the button from your .xib into the associated .swift file.

In your ViewController you do something like this :

```
let button:UIButton!

[...]

button.targetForAction("tappedButton:", withSender: self)

func tappedButton() {
    print("Taped !")
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i made about what you said, but get the error: http://i.imgur.com/G1cD3Hz.png

Comment: Sorry my bad. You have got to load your xib file as a subView.

Look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857986/load-a-uiview-from-nib-in-swift#26326006

and from here if `subView` is the name of your loaded xib file.

`subView.button.targetForAction ...`

Comment: Yes, i have loaded: `code`       let customView = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("ViewCallout", owner: self, options: nil))[0] as! CustomCalloutView;`code`
  But i cant finally understand, can you please look my project on github?
        

        let calloutViewFrame = customView.frame;

Comment: You have to put this code inside your viewController but your .xib file need it's own .swift file.

look here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5SKUXSuDOw