# creating custom UIView

Tags: swift, uiview

i am trying to create a custom UIView in a separate swift file with code like this

```
import UIKit
class CustomView : UIView {
    var contentView:UIView?
    // other outlets

    override init(frame: CGRect) { // for using CustomView in code
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) { // for using CustomView in IB
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.commonInit()
        fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)
        guard let content = contentView else { return }
        content.frame = self.bounds
        content.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        self.addSubview(content)
    }
}
```

then i call it in a viewcontroller with code like this

```
var custom:CustomView! = CustomView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        custom.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        view.addSubview(custom)
    }
```

yet i got an error like this:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:
(loaded)' with name 'CustomView''
```

Why do i get this error code? i have look everywhere on youtube, google,even some stackoverflow answer that similar to this. And they all did the same thing as i did but i am the only one that got this error. i dont know what NIB bundle is. and how do make this custom UIView work

Comment: If you don't know what a NIB bundle is, then why did you write code to load your custom view from a NIB?

Comment: its the only way that i could find on the internet, if there are any other way to create custom UIVIew? please let me know, cause i dont know

Comment: You don't need a NIB. Just write the code.

Comment: You tried to load a Nib named CustomView but you did not create a NIB or XIB file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26018312/9137841 can you refer this ?

Answer (score 0):

The name of your xib must match the string you pass in when you load it: `Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)`

You are saying here that the name of your xib in your project is `CustomView`. Check that it has that name in Xcode
s project navigatior, like this:

[image: Project Navigator XIB name]

If that is correct, ensure that it is installed correctly by opening the File inspector (⌘ + ⌥ + 1 / Command + option + 1) and checking the `Target Membership` box is checked. Here it is shown as `ProjectName` right at the bottom:

[image: Checking target membership]

Comment: sorry if i sound like a noob, but i dont get it why do i need to have .xib file? is there other way that i can make custom UIView without it?

Comment: The code example you provided indicated you were trying to load a xib file that you had already created. There are three options for making a custom view subclass: Interface builder using a xib, interface builder inside a storyboard, or programatically (all code, no interface builder).

Comment: how do i do it programatically?

Comment: [Here is examples of creating custom views](https://github.com/codepath/ios_guides/wiki/Custom-Views). It includes code examples of creating a view programatically as well as using interface builder. The 4th heading is creating a view programatically.