# Re-using complex custom UI elements - Xcode Storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, storyboard

In Xcode on the StoryBoard I built a complex UI element consisting of many sub-views.

I encapsulated it all into a UIView subclass but each element has to be built out on the storyboard wherever it is used.

Is there a way to build it in such a way that all a developer would need to do to use it is to add a UIView of the appropriate sub-class and not need to layout all of the subviews? Similar to how we do not need to interact with the underlying structure of buttons or labels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, but it requires a bit of a workaround. It basically requires you to create a UIView subclass, which loads all it's subviews from a separate nib file

[This question has the answers for you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857986/load-a-uiview-from-nib-in-swift)

Comment: Thanks! I was able to accomplish this by creating a xib of what I wanted and then subclassing UIView that read from the xib. I also subclassed a UIView that only contains the UIView that reads the xib and am able to load the xib from the container without the viewController needing to do anything.