# How to add a subview to a custom view programatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add a subview (UIButton) in my custom view. However, when I do addSubview() in my created function, it won't add the UIButton, even when I call setNeedsLayout(). I call the addButton() in the ViewController

```
class PlayingField: UIView {

    var buttons: [UIButton] = []

    func addButton() {
        let button = UIButton()
        addSubview(button)
        buttons.append(button)
        setNeedsLayout()
        layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        for i in buttons.indices {
            buttons[i].frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)
            buttons[i].backgroundColor = UIColor.green
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try setNeedsLayout()  and than  layoutIfNeeded()?

Comment: Without further constraints all buttons are placed on top of each other. Is this intended?

Comment: Right now, I just want to display a single UIButton on screen. When I figure out how to do this, then I will add constraints to every button so they don't overlap.

Comment: Your (original) code added the button fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are able to draw your `CustomView`? Do you see any other components in this view?

Because if you have an `xib` file bound to this file, then you might need to load nib. You can find an answer for how to do it here: [Load UIView from nib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857986/load-a-uiview-from-nib-in-swift)

If not, you might have a problem that `layoutSubviews`wasn't called and that's why you were not adding subview at all.

Comment: When I add the UIButton directly on layoutSubViews(), it works (it draws all the UIButtons that are in the buttons array), however it only gets called once in the beginning. So when I update the buttons array, it does not update the view.

Comment: Then you might consider using `StackView`. If you do so, you can add your buttons easily and well-organised using `addArrangedSubviews`

Answer (score 0):

Using the original code you posted, here is a complete example:

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    var buttons: [UIButton] = []

    func addButton() {
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100))
        buttons.append(button)
        setNeedsLayout()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        for i in buttons.indices {
            buttons[i].frame = bounds.offsetBy(dx: CGFloat(20), dy: CGFloat(20))
            buttons[i].backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            addSubview(buttons[i])
        }
    }
}

class CustomViewController: UIViewController {

    let cView: CustomView = {
        let v = CustomView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .cyan
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.addSubview(cView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240),
            cView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120),
            cView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            cView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            ])

        cView.addButton()
    }

}
```

Result - cyan rect is the `CustomView` ... black rect is the button:

[image]

As a side note, this works, but using `layoutSubviews()` to add elements is not a great idea.