# how to show xib view when tap on textfield right button

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, xib, nib

I want to show a popup view when tap on textfield right button, I tried
 below code but view is not showing when tap on textfield right button.
, I created xib view with "CustomeView" class name as below and I am
, trying to load in alert view

```
  class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

      let textFieldRightButton = UIButton(type: .infoLight)
    var textFieldOne:UITextField? = nil
    var alertview:UIView? = nil

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2, execute: {

            self.showAlertViewWithTextField(title: "Test", msg: "Test Custome View", okActionTitle: "continue", cancelActionTitle: "Cancel", success: {
                print("Continue")
            }) {
                print("Cancel")
            }

        })
    }

    func showAlertViewWithTextField(title: String, msg: String, okActionTitle:String, cancelActionTitle:String, success: (() -> Void)? , cancel: (() -> Void)?)
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
        alertview = alert.view

        textFieldRightButton.tintColor = UIColor.red

        alert.addTextField
            {
                (textField) in
                textField.placeholder = "Enter text."
                textField.delegate = self
                textField.rightViewMode = .always
                textField.rightView = self.textFieldRightButton

        }

        textFieldOne = alert.textFields?.first

         textFieldRightButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showPopupMsg), for: .touchUpInside)

        let successAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: okActionTitle, style: .destructive)
        {
            action -> Void in
            success?()
        }
        let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: cancelActionTitle, style: .cancel)
        {
            action -> Void in
            cancel?()
        }

        alert.addAction(successAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func showPopupMsg() {
        alertview?.addSubview(CustomeView(frame: CGRect(x: textFieldOne!.frame.minX, y: textFieldOne!.frame.minX, width: 100, height: 50)))
    }

}
```

**below is my custom view**

```
  class CustomeView: UIView {
            @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
            @IBOutlet weak var messageText: UILabel!

            override init(frame: CGRect) {
                super.init(frame: frame)
                commonInit()
            }

            required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
             super.init(coder: aDecoder)
                commonInit()
            }

            private func commonInit(){
                Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomeView", owner: self, options: nil)
                addSubview(contentView)
                contentView.frame = self.bounds
                contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
           }

        }
```

**How can I show this nib view in view controller?**

Comment: Hint: IBOutlet connection

Comment: I connected iboulets.

Comment: What is it today? A free upvote day? BTW here is a great answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26326006/8374890

Comment: You have made an IBOutlet connection to what!?

Comment: to label and view in xib

Comment: IBOutlet-connect the custom view you have created, silly.

Comment: What kind of error you're getting ? Anything like bad access ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with your code snippet and I got bad access error. Try removing the custom class (CustomeView) of that xib file and set the `CustomeView` view class in `File's Owner` of that xib file. Also check your `messageText` and `contentView` outlet object type should be the `File's Owner`.

[image: Outlet]

[image: File Owner]