# How to eliminate redundant contentView when creating custom view via XIB?

Tags: ios, swift

Based on https://medium.com/better-programming/swift-3-creating-a-custom-view-from-a-xib-ecdfe5b3a960, this is a common technique, to build a custom view via XIB.

```
import UIKit

class CustomView: UIView {
  @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var mainLabel: UILabel!
  
  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
  }
  
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
  }
  
  private func commonInit() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options nil)
    addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.frame = self.bounds
    contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
  }
}
```

---

We will end up with the following custom view.

```
|-----------------------|
|   CustomView UIView   |
| |-------------------| |
| |  Content UIView   | |
| | |---------------| | |
| | |   UILabel     | | |
| | |---------------| | |
| |                   | |
| |-------------------| |
|                       |
|-----------------------|
```

However, since custom view itself is already an `UIView`, isn't it seem redundant, to have yet another `UIView` in itself?

Having a `UIView` (`contentView`) in another `UIView` (`CustomView`) seem serve no real purpose other than slowing down UI performance.

Isn't it will be better, if we can have something as following?

```
|-----------------------|
|   CustomView UIView   |
|   |---------------|   |
|   |   UILabel     |   |
|   |---------------|   |
|                       |
|-----------------------|
```

---

In Android ecosystem, we may solve this by using [merge](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts#Merge) tag. Its description is as follow.

> The  tag helps eliminate redundant view groups in your view
> hierarchy when including one layout within another. For example, if
> your main layout is a vertical LinearLayout in which two consecutive
> views can be re-used in multiple layouts, then the re-usable layout in
> which you place the two views requires its own root view. However,
> using another LinearLayout as the root for the re-usable layout would
> **result in a vertical LinearLayout inside a vertical LinearLayout**. The
> nested LinearLayout serves no real purpose other than to slow down
> your UI performance.

Is there anything equivalent, when we are building custom view using XIB?

Comment: You don't need the content view. Check this, there are some hints in the answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24857986/load-a-uiview-from-nib-in-swift